# What's the maximum amount of time I might have to wait to ask again after encountering "You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period"?

Tags: support, questions

If there are a maximum of fifty questions per thirty days, then what is the maximum amount of time before it is then possible to ask a question again, after receiving this message?

While I haven't sat down with pencil and paper to try and figure out the answer, I would expect that, within a day, this message would expire.

Comment: The moment you are being given that message, you have to ask yourself if you are not perhaps asking *too many questions altogether*.

Comment: Related: [50 question per month limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217) Please do read the reactions there to someone asking for the rate limit to be lifted.

Comment: Last but not least, this is a legitimate support question. It should be voted on in that light; it doesn't need to be down voted if you feel that hitting the limit is a problem.

Comment: The maximum? 30 days. :-)

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: I assume you mean "Minimum", not "Maximum".  Because if you want the maximum, you have the option of waiting ∞ days.  (Just a minor grammar thing)

Comment: @Pokechu22: No, it's right, because it's the time he HAS TO wait, not the time he is ALLOWED TO wait.

Comment: @KenWhite it's actually not thirty days because, as Shog9 explains, there are other constraints.  I don't believe it's possible to post fifty questions within the span of hours -- but I intend to find out.

Comment: @Thufir: You did notice that this  post is more than 4 years old, right?  And that my comment ended with **:-)**? And the question did ask what the **maximum** period would be. The **maximum** is 30 days; whether the poster can ever achieve that maximum is irrelevant, the max is still 30 days.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I would expect it that, within a day, that this message would expire.

That only works if you've asked a consistent number of questions per day for the last 30 days.

If, for example, you asked one question every 14 hours and 24 minutes for 30 days, and then - after asking the 50th question on the 30th day, you *immediately* tried to ask *another* question, you'd find yourself blocked with this message - but would only need to wait the normal 14.4 hour period before asking again.

On the other hand, if you somehow managed to post 50 questions in the space of *one* day, you would have to wait an entire 30 days before you could ask again. There are other rate-limits, so you would find it quite difficult to accomplish this - but, if you were sufficiently dedicated, it is possible *in theory*.

Most people are somewhere between these two extremes, so the easiest way to figure out how long you'll have to wait is to just count back 50 questions from your most recent, and look at the creation date of the 50th - 30 days from that date, you'll be able to ask again. Of course, if you've *deleted* any of those questions, you'll have to remember to count those too, but otherwise you can just use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&pagesize=50&q=user%3ame%20is%3aquestion) to find the 50th question.

Comment: Will the search include my deleted questions if I use the `user:me` flag? If so, does it also show your own deleted questions if you a sub 20k rep user?

Comment: It won't. For most folks, including the OP, it makes no difference; i mention it only for completeness.

Comment: since we're talking 30-days time frame, worth reminding that one can see deleted questions in profile, as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted): "deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 60 days, can be seen using..."

Comment: Yeah, worth keeping in mind I suppose - though realistically, if you're getting this message and have enough deleted questions for it to *matter*, you have bigger problems.